# completableFuture.complete() not working inside addOnSuccessListener

Tags: java, android, kotlin, future, completable-future

I have the following code:

```
private fun genericFunction(): CompletableFuture<Location?> {
    val completableFuture = CompletableFuture<Location?>()

    Executors.newCachedThreadPool().submit {
        val fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                    Toast.makeText(...).show()
                    completableFuture.complete(location)
                }
    }
    
    return completableFuture
}
```

I would like to be able to complete the CompletableFuture from the `addOnSuccessListener` listener. The problem is that, if I don't wait for the `Future`, the `Toast` is correctly shown. If I wait for the `Future` the app freezes. My guess is that the `completableFuture.complete()` cannot be called from `addOnSuccessListener`, but it's very strange since the reference to `completableFuture` is valid inside the `Listener`.

Any idea about what's the problem? Can I do something to debug?

Comment: Where and how are you waiting for the future?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have another function (let's call it `firstFunction()`) from which I call `genericFunction()`. From `firstFunction()`, I wait for the Future with `.get()`. To debug I have tried by calling `completableFuture.complete(null)` from outside the Listener (in `genericFunction()`) so that `firstFunction()` thinks that the Future has completed. In this case, the Toast is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `CompletableFuture.allOf(...).get()`.

I solved by changing:

```
val currentLocationFuture = getCurrentLocation()
val currentActivityFuture = getCurrentActivity()
CompletableFuture.allOf(currentLocationFuture, currentActivityFuture).get()
val currentLocation = currentLocationFuture.get()
val currentActivity = currentActivityFuture.get()
// ...
```

to:

```
val currentLocationFuture = getCurrentLocation()
val currentActivityFuture = getCurrentActivity()
CompletableFuture.allOf(currentLocationFuture, currentActivityFuture).thenApply {
    val currentLocation = currentLocationFuture.get()
    val currentActivity = currentActivityFuture.get()
    // ...
}
```